# how to set up elasticsearch and kibana on windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I tried to set-up a elasticsearch on my windows 7 os pc. Installed elasticsearch & sense and it's working as the loacahost:9200 is working fine.

Now i am strugging to search in a file located at c:\user\rajesh\default.json.

indexing of a data i.e

```
Put test\te\2
{
---datas
}
```

is working fine, but when i try to reference to file i.e `POST test\te\2-d @default.json` it's giving error as Unexpected '<'

I Installed KIBANA but not able to do anything with it's UI. when trying to search anything it's giving error:No index found at `http://localhost:9200/INDEX_MISSING/_mapping/field/`

I have edited config.js file with elasticsearch: "http://"+"localhost"+":9200", but it is not able to use the index which i created using sense to ES.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty
```

If you get no data returned (no indices), then you have some error either in elistcsearch or logstash.

Additionally, I recomend you try to access kopf from your browser.

```
http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9200
```

If you have data in the port, it will show you the indexes.

Regards

Ari